# detectar solo cierre de navegador con Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9, angular10

Hola necesito saber cuando se ejecuta el cierre del navegador, en intentado con el siguiente codigo pero tambien se ejecuta cuando se cierra una pestaña y necesito que se ejecute solo cuando cierro el navegador por completo.

```
@HostListener('window:unload', [ '$event' ])
  unloadHandler(event) {
    this.authService.logout();
  }
```

agradezco quien me pueda colaborar